# Has the "right to assemble" (US 1st Amendment) ever been shown to apply to just two persons?

Tags: us-constitution, first-amendment

Has the "right to assemble" (US 1st Amendment) ever been shown to apply to just two persons?  I was just wondering if it had ever been applied to as few as two persons.  (Or even one person in fact.)  I wonder if that's still an open question or can one or two people "assemble"?  What constitutes "assembly"?

Comment: How would it even be *possible* to infringe your right to assemble with yourself?

Comment: @cpast To be fair, the text doesn't say anything about the right to assemble *with* anyone, only the right to *assemble* in relation to the right to petition, so the question isn't as trivial to write off.

Comment: @Dawn doesn't an assembly require at least two elements (i.e., people)?  The right for one person to go somewhere is the right of freedom of movement, not the right of assembly.

Comment: @phoog You've just restated the question. I'm working on an answer. And you're right, the right for one person to go somewhere doesn't implicate the right to assemble.

Comment: @Dawn I haven't exactly restated the question.  The question is whether the right to assemble can apply to one or two persons.  I am challenging your statement that "the text doesn't say anything about the right to assemble *with* anyone" because I believe that the definition of "assemble" necessarily implies "with at least one other person." I would argue that two people can exercise a right to assemble, but one person cannot.

Comment: Okay. If that answer satisfies you, cool.

Comment: JW.  Do you think what Rocky did in preparation for his fight with Apollo during that whole montage scene constituted assembly?  If so, that's with just one person.

Comment: @Mr.A Not even a little bit, and I'm not sure what strange definition of "assemble" you have that would include it.

Comment: Well, @cpast, in some sense I was thinking he was "getting himself assembled"

Comment: @Mr.A *assembly* in this context means the gathering of more than one person together in one place.  The fact that it can mean other things in other contexts does not mean that those other things are constitutionally protected.

Comment: ok, @cpast, but there's just one more example to contemplate.  You ever see the "Leeroy Jenkins" episode of South Park?  What if you have somebody that writes a rousing letter to a bunch of activists which fails to stir the emotions of even one of them.  As a result, on the day of the event, only the original petitioner shows up.  Has that guy assembled?

Comment: @Mr.A His right is irrelevant at that point. It only matters once you start considering whether a particular government action would infringe upon that right. What action do you propose could conceivably infringe on his freedom of assembly?

Comment: @cpast - suppose there was a "no loitering" statute which prohibited singles from mingling in a certain area.  suppose that law was crafted knowing that assembly by groups couldnt be stopped, but they felt they could stop a single person from hanging out on a sidewalk.